# Radius of convergence for a power series where coefficients are given by recursive relation

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, power-series

Problem: Let $f(z) = \sum_{n \geq 0} a_n z^n$ be the formal power series with coefficients given by the following recursive relation: given $\alpha, \beta \in \mathbb{R}$,
$$a_0 = 0$$
$$a_1 = 1$$
and
$$a_n = \alpha a_{n-1} + \beta \alpha_{n-2} $$
for $n \geq 2$. Prove that the radius of convergence of $f(z)$ is nonzero.

Attempt: I am trying to prove this by invoking the Cauchy-Hadmard theorem. That is,
$$\frac{ 1}{r} = \limsup | a_n |^{ 1/n} $$
but of course it is not clear whether an explicit formula for the $a_n$ can be found. Is there an alternative way to find the radius of convergence?

Comment: the recurrence $a_n = \alpha a_{n-1} + \beta \alpha_{n-2}$ is solvable in terms of the characteristic equation roots ($x^2-\alpha x -\beta=0$ obtained by assuming one has $a_n=ca^n$ and finding what $a$ works) but there are various forms depending whether roots are real, complex, simple, double etc so it's easier to prove inductively (easily just triangle ineq) that if $c=\max (|\alpha|,|\beta|)$ one has $|a_n| \le (2c)^n$ from which result follows

Comment: The power series has a rational [generating function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generating_function). The poles of this rational function are the zeros of the denominator. The radius of converge is directly related to these zeros.

Comment: @Conrad Is this true? It does not hold for $n =1$, for certain choices of $\alpha, \beta$.

Comment: Technically you are right if above $c<1$ (though of course that is a trivial case since then $|a_n| \le 2^n$) so let $c=\max (|\alpha|,|\beta|,1)$ and then it should work

Comment: @Conrad Even then, I am getting

$$|a_n| = | \alpha a_{n-1} + \beta a_{n-2} | \leq c | a_{n-1} + a_{n-2} | \leq 2c | (2c)^{n-1}  + (2c)^{n-2}  |  = (2c)^{n}  + (2c)^{n-1} = ( 2c)^n ( 1 + (2c)^{-1})$$

so it is still not bounded above. How are you landing on $(2c)^n$ as a possible upper bound for $|a_n|$?

Comment: Note that if $c\ge 1$ so $c^n$ increases then $|a_n| \le c(|a_{n-1}|+|a_{n-2}|) \le 2c(2c)^{n-1}$ by induction

Answer (score 1):

We obtain with the Ansatz
\begin{align*}
\color{blue}{\sum_{n\geq 2}a_nz^n}&=\alpha\sum_{n\geq 2}a_{n-1}z^n+\beta\sum_{n\geq 2}a_{n-2}z^n\\
&=\alpha z\sum_{n\geq 2}a_{n-1}z^{n-1}+\beta z^2\sum_{n\geq 2}a_{n-2}z^{n-2}\\
&\,\,\color{blue}{=\alpha z\sum_{n\geq 1} a_nz^n+\beta z^2\sum_{n\geq 0}a_nz^n}\tag{1}
\end{align*}
It follows from (1) with $a_0=0$ and $a_1=1$:
\begin{align*}
f(z)-z&=\alpha zf(z)+\beta z^2f(z)\\
f(z)\left(1-\alpha z-\beta z^2\right)&=z\\
\color{blue}{f(z)}&\color{blue}{=\frac{z}{1-\alpha z-\beta z^2}}\tag{2}
\end{align*}
The zeros $z_{1,2}$ of the denominator of $f(z)$ are
\begin{align*}
\beta z^2+\alpha z-1&=0\\
z_{1,2}&=\frac{1}{2\beta}\left(-\alpha \pm\sqrt{\alpha^2+4\beta}\right)\tag{3}
\end{align*}

> The radius of convergence of the power series expansion of $f$ at $z=0$ is given by the distance from $0$ to the nearest singularity. Since depending on $\alpha,\beta\in\mathbb{R}$ we have zero, one, or two poles, we obtain from the representation (2) and the zeros (3)
> \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{R=\begin{cases}
> \frac{1}{2\left|\beta\right|}\max\left\{\left|-\alpha\pm\sqrt{\alpha^2+4\beta}\right|\right\}&\qquad\alpha\in\mathbb{R},\beta\in\mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\}\\
> \frac{1}{|\alpha|}&\qquad\alpha\in\mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\}, \beta=0\\
> \infty&\qquad\alpha=\beta=0
> \end{cases}}
> \end{align*}
> and the claim $R>0$ follows.

Comment: This looks like it works but isn't very helpful, as its way more complicated than how this problem was intended to be solved.

Comment: @kam: Here I provide more information than you need just for the sake of background information. If you are familiar with this approach it boils down to simply solve the quadratic equation. From it everything can be derived.